# Retrieving user/profile list from membership provider insanely slow

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-membership

I have an application that has been taken from a sharepoint user control and converted to plain web pages. Everything is working fine - I can sign up and retrieve my password, etc. However, when I try and display the registered users the results will take 2+ minutes. Going to page 2 of results takes another 2+ minutes and so on. At last count we had less than 3000 users.

More details - In addition to rebranding the app to aspx pages, it has been connected to a different database server. The previous server (Server 2008, SQL server 2005) serves up membership pretty quickly, but the new server (Server 2016, SQL Server 2017) takes forever. Is there a setting or configuration that I am missing when it comes to getting users from Membership Provider? Please let me know if I need to supply more detail.

Edit - the tables were restored to the new server from the old, if that makes a difference.

Here is the execution plan! https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkNBZyp_U

Comment: Sorry SQL Server 2017

Comment: I've added the plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy7A2R3d8

Comment: sorry - I thought the stored procedure was it, how would i find it? I followed the instructions on the site you linked

Comment: I think I have it - its newly edited